# Finding the limits for integration.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

[image]

How do we get 0.5 <= u <= 1 and -u <= v <= u over here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have a trapezoid $(x,y)\in\Box(1,0)(2,0)(2,0)(1,0)$, and choose to rotate and rescale using $u=(x+y)/2, v=(y-x)/2$.

After this transformation we have: $(u,v) \in\Box(\tfrac 12, -\tfrac 12)(1,-1)(1,1)(\tfrac 1 2, \tfrac 12)$

Hence this transformed region is: $\tfrac 12 \leq u\leq 1$ and $-u\leq v\leq u$

Sketching a diagram of that trapezoid might help you see why.

Answer (score 0):

First, rephrase (x,y) in A as inequalities. 
Second, determine (u,v) from (x,y).
Third, translate this to the bounds.